# Constructing a User Profile for Music Taste

Tags: machine-learning, categorical-data, recommender-system, mad, musical-data-analysis

My goal is to construct User profiles based on positive (and maybe also negative) interactions with songs. A User has the option to like a song. This would give me a list of likes for each user. With for example the Spotify API I can extract different features of songs: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/#/operations/get-audio-features
So for each song i would have categorical features (like genre) and numerical features (like danceability).

I want to create a good user profile that represents the musical taste of the user with a certain confidence that includes the mentioned features.

I have been doing a lot of research but I mainly find info on recommender systems and not on user profiles.

Would it be as simple as computing the average over all liked tracks for numerical features and the top ranks for the categorical features?

This approach seems a little bit to simple for me, any ideas?

Comment: One obvious ideas is a recommender system approach, after which you then could try to interpret the user embeddings that get created?

Comment: @Björn thanks for the idea. I will look into it. Do all content based recommender systems create user embeddings of the underlying features?

Comment: You can do recommender systems in many ways, but the version with an embeddings for users and for content  is an extremely popular version (usually implemented using neural network frameworks).

Comment: @Björn so I think you are talking about Matrix Factorization where the Rating Matrix gets factorized into two matrices, the user and item matrix. Is it true that I already have an item matrix since I can get the features from Spotify API and only need to train the user matrix to complete the recommender system?

Comment: I don't know what you get from the Spotify API. I'd have thought it would be unusual to provide internally used embeddings, but perhaps they do. Yes, matrix factorisation is the vanilla version of a "deep" (not really in that case) learning recommender system with embeddings.